# $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \quad x_0 =3$ find Taylor expansion using term-by term approach

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion

I have a function and I have to find the taylor series expansion using term by term integration and differentiation:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \quad x_0 =3$$

Well, my concern is that I only know the general formula

$$\sum \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}\cdot(x-x_0)^n$$

Which is the easiest, but not allowed to use, but how should I proceed using term-by-term approach? I failed to find some real examples, only general theory (that's why I took the simplest example to understand the idea).

Comment: Do you need an intuitive explanation for this? If so, watch: https://youtu.be/3d6DsjIBzJ4?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr

Comment: Miniscule comment, but note that the $(x-x_0)$ should be raised to the $n^\text{th}$ power for the formula to be valid.

Comment: @Decaf-Math, oops, that was misstype, fixed

Comment: What is the "term-by term approach"? For this particular example one approach could be to compute the first few derivatives $f'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^3}$, $f''(x) = \frac{2\cdot 3}{x^4}$, $f'''(x) = -\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot 4}{x^5}$ and notice the pattern to get you the general formula (and you prove the formula with induction).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{-3-(x-3)}\right)=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1+(x-3)/3}\right).$$
But
$$
\frac{1}{1+(x-3)/3}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^k(x-3)^k.
$$
Hence, for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-3|<3$,
$$
f(x)=-\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^kk(x-3)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^{k+1}k(x-3)^{k-1}.
$$